# How to remove a value from this ConcurrentHashMap<String,ConcurrentHashMap<String,ArrayList>>

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I have a ConcurrentHashMap in the below format:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,ConcurrentHashMap<String,ArrayList>>
```

Now in this map,I want to remove a particular value in the array list.Can anybody guide with this.

EDIT1:
I have a map
<"packet1"--><"NR1",[Pr1,Pr2]>>
<"packet1"--><"NR2",[Pr1,Pr2]>>

Now when i remove map.get("packet1").get("NR1").remove("Pr2") it removes Pr2 from both NR1 and NR2.Isnt should remove only from NR1.Am i doing anything wrong here.plz update me,

P.S : I am updated the map for the second time for the same key packet1 with both values NR1 and NR2

Comment: Well there will be *several* array lists - do you know the two keys involved? Note that `ArrayList` *isn't* thread-safe - what's the threading situation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake setting up the map. When you added the lists for NR1 and NR2, you used the *same* list object. Your map now contains two references to that list. When you remove the element from the NR1 list, you're removing it from the same list that is visible under NR2.

The solution is to fix your code, so that when you insert a list into the map, you insert a *different* list for each key.

You say in a comment on JB's post that you didn't do this. The fact is, you *did* do this. You just haven't realised it yet!

Answer (score 2):

You simply do

```
// Get hold of the map containing the list
Map<String, ArrayList> innerMap = yourMap.get("primaryKey");

// Get hold of the list
ArrayList listToRemoveFrom = innerMap.get("secondaryKey");

// Remove from the list
listToRemoveFrom.remove(objectToRemove);
```

or, in a single line:

```
yourMap.get("yourPrimaryKey").get("yourSecondaryKey").remove(objectToRemove);
```

---

As Jim Garrison points out, unless you're certain that your map contains `"yourPrimaryKey"`, and your inner map contains `"yourSecondaryKey"` you need to check for `null`s in each case.

---

As a side-note: I encourage you to use generics all the way through, and specify which element type your `ArrayList` will contain by declaring the map as

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,ConcurrentHashMap<String,ArrayList<SomeType>>>
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, even better, code against interfaces if possible, and write

```
Map<String,Map<String,List<SomeType>>>
```

Comment: +1 and I'd mention the possibility of the `get()` calls returning null, causing NPE :-)

Comment: It's removed from both lists, because you've added the same list twice. Both NR1 and NR2 points to *the same* list! When inserting the list you need to insert a copy of the list (if you want to be able to remove an element from one list but not the other.)

Answer (score 2):

```
map.get("key1").get("key2").remove(particularValue);
```

Each time I see such a structure, I wonder why a `Key` class, containing the two String keys and implementing equals and hashCode properly, is not used instead. The map would then become a `Map<Key, List<Foo>>`.

And should even be implemented (using Guava) using a `MultiMap<Key, Foo>`, which would make it easier to use and maintain.

Comment: To be fair, Guava does not currently maintain thread-safe multimap implementations...though it's not clear whether or not the OP expects true thread-safety.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt the map of maps of lists of the OP is thread-safe without any synchronization anyway. If the OP doesn't even know how to remove an item from this structure, I don't see how he could make sure that the usage of the structure is thread-safe: it's a much more complex problem.

Comment: Remember that collections don't store copies of objects. They store references to objects. You stored two references to the same List object in your Map. So, if you remove an item from one, it's removed from the other, since both lists are in fact the same unique one. Make sure to store two different List instances (containing the same Strings initially) in the map.

Comment: thats a manual mistake.. both are "packet1"..but still for me it deletes both the keys!!

Comment: What you have is impossible. A map doesn't support duplicate keys.

Comment: P.S : I am updated the map for the second time for the same key packet1 with both values NR1 and NR2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8734/discussion-between-kiddo-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Make an SSCCE, and post it, so that I can understand what you're doing.